# cannot import tif file into matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation

i am trying to import a `.tif` image into matlab with the following code

```
>> aa = imread('house.tif');
```

i get the error

```
Error using rtifc
TIFF library error: '_TIFFVSetField: C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\house.tif: Null count
for "Tag 34022" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1).'.

Error in readtif (line 49)
[X, map, details] = rtifc(args);

Error in imread (line 434)
[X, map] = feval(fmt_s.read, filename, extraArgs{:});
```

as i am using matlab for the first time in my life i really have no idea what this error means. Please help is required in this matter.

Comment: does the tiff file open with other applications? which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: yes it opens normally with every other application.I am using R2012b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB R2012b has a bug and it cannot read TIFF files properly. More information can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/326232

Answer (score 0):

Probably Matlab does not support the specific type of tif. In Matlab's defence, tif is not an easy file-format to read. It supports plenty of compression schemes, multiple pages and who knows what. I'd convert the tif to png and go with that.

Update: A quick Google search revealed that "rtifc" is a Matlab mex-wrapper around libtiff. Your error appears to come from libtiff. If the latter can't read it, your tif will probably be problematic for a lot of other applications too.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is use the implementation `tiffread` from François Nedelec's group at EMBL. http://www.embl.de/ExternalInfo/nedelec/misc/matlab/tiffread29.m. It's heavily used by biology folks all over the world. I've been using it for many years.

Comment: nahh i am just learning the basics, nothing serious. have found another images for my learning thanks however for your time :)

Comment: In case you run into this again, just copy that file and use it just like you would use `imread`.